# How to check efficiently if a column contains given values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `TBL1` which contains columns, among them `COL1`.

I want to check as efficiently as possible (quick computation, small result) if the values `"foo"`, `"bar"` and `"bar2"` are found in `COL1`, and report which are missing.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

The version is "19.00.0000", the table structure and index might vary as this is meant to be applied on various cases (i.e. `COL1` might be indexed or not).

Comment: can you share table structures, indexes, version you use?

Comment: I didn\`t downvote, but I think there are too many situations. For example, if the table are empty, then you don\`t have to check existence. Also you can have a separate table that stores all values that inserted into this table, and other things, probably I am wrong, but I personally think it is too wide a question.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate, the question is general because I don't know anything about TBL1 except it has a COL1 column, so I can't make assumptions on emptiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your words in a separate table/cte that you LEFT JOIN tbl1. Something like:

```
with cte (c1) as (select 'foo' from dual
                  union all
                  select 'bar' from dual
                  union all
                  select 'bar2' from dual)
select c1
from cte
left join tbl1 on cte.c1 = tbl1.col1
where tbl1.col1 is null;
```

Make sure to have a tbl1.col1 index.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/mjAU2YPP

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `minus` set operator:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     tbl1 (col1)                      --> this is your table (you don't
  3     AS                                   have to type it here, as a CTE)
  4        (SELECT 'foo' FROM DUAL         
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'xyz' FROM DUAL),
  7     cte (c1)                         --> this is table that contains
  8     AS                               --  values you're checking; could
  9        (SELECT 'foo' FROM DUAL       --  be "real" table, or a CTE as in 
 10         UNION ALL                    --  this example
 11         SELECT 'bar' FROM DUAL
 12         UNION ALL
 13         SELECT 'bar2' FROM DUAL)
 14  SELECT c1 FROM cte                  --> finally, the query itself
 15  MINUS
 16  SELECT col1 FROM tbl1;

C1
----
bar
bar2

SQL>
```

Comment: Does Oracle also support the ANSI/ISO SQL `EXCEPT`?

Comment: @jarlh, it is available in **21c** version (and above). Lower versions (I tried it on 18c) don't support it, as far as I can tell.